# android studio - I accidently clicked the "background" button on a download, now I cant find the download progress

Tags: android

I am quite new to android stuido and I clicked the "background" button while downloading android 10 (API 29) and now I cant find the progress
I have seen answers saying:
window -> background tasks -> show
But I don't know how to get there.

This has probably been answered but I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

[image]

check that first

[image]

and here you can find background tasks

Comment: All I see running is it setting up the project, no download progress :/
Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: you are welcome ,maybe it's finish the download?

Comment: maybe but my  internet is junk and it was going quite slow... One option is just to let it go overnight and hope it is done by then.